# Order of constructor and copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Could someone tell me why does in such case copy constructor and destructor is used by program?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
public:
        Object(){}
        Object(const Object &kk) {cout<<"kk"<<endl;}
        bool operator==(Object c)
        {
                cout<<"o=="<<endl; return false;
        }
        ~Object()
        {
                cout<<"des"<<endl;
        }

};

int main()
{
        Object o1,o2;
        bool result;
        result = (o1==o2);
}
```

The result is:

```
kk
o==
des
```

Thanks in advance for answer.

Comment: You _should_ have three `des`s. Is this the whole output?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cda48c84215619dc

Comment: Yes there are 3 des. Just wrote this 1. Lightness Races in Orbit has already answered my question and I have remind myself why it is like that.

Comment: Lol! Sorry some other name displayed when I was writing it!

Comment: I've been Lightness for at least two days now :P

Answer (score 2):

Because your `operator==` takes its argument by value.

Taking by value implies a copy.

Make it take a const-reference instead, like you did for your copy constructor.